# How was the 'bump' removed from the Airbus P2F?

Tags: aircraft-design, cargo, airbus-a330

[image]
(Sources: [airliners.net](http://www.airliners.net/photo/DHL/Airbus-A330-300P2F/4720171), [YouTube](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/6vjyoEn3xtM/maxresdefault.jpg))

How was the 'bump' removed from [the design of] the Airbus P2F?

The A330 Freighter based on the A330-200 features a [bump / blister / bulge](https://www.flightglobal.com/news/articles/picture-airbus-a330f-gets-blister-for-new-nose-gear-211629/) that raises the nose landing gear to level the cargo deck for easier loading of cargo. A design issue with the passenger A330 is the slanted floor, but it was not a big deal since cargo with feet manages.

> The A330/A340's distinctive nose-down pitch - which is greater than intended in the original design and only emerged when production of the aircraft began in the early 1990s - was a problem that Airbus had addressed on the first version of the A350.

The passenger-to-freighter (P2F) conversion program for both the -200 and -300 lacks this bump. What design change was incorporated into the conversion that fixed the floor level?

---

The latest information I could find is from October 2009 (8 years ago):

Airbus abandoned the 'bump' modification in favor of a special ground jack to level the deck during loading/unloading.

> Airbus is proposing a piece of external ground-support equipment which would physically lift the aircraft, producing the same effect as the lowered gear in new-build freighters ([flightglobal.com](https://www.flightglobal.com/news/articles/airbus-proposes-jack-to-avoid-modifying-a330-p2f-nose-334182/)).

Comment: Did they fix the floor level?

Comment: Because your link says they made the change in order to level the "cabin" floor for easier loading.

Comment: Maybe with the P2F they changed the floor and not the landing gear?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The A330 P2F features a fully-powered Cargo Loading System (CLS) that is perfectly capable of loading/unloading even the heaviest pallets even with the aircraft "on the tilt". Therefore, no 'tilt remedy' is required.

[Flight Global, 15 February, 2012](https://www.flightglobal.com/news/articles/singapore-a330p2f-to-become-a-reality-with-help-from-st-368286/):

> The P2F version will retain the passenger aircraft's geometry and incorporate a powered cargo loading system to enable pallets to be moved "uphill" on the main cargo deck.

Comment: The front landing gear jack sounded cheaper.